# MaterialShapeDrawable makes my CardView invisible on API 28 and below

Tags: android, android-cardview, material-components-android

I'm using this piece of code to give some shape to my cardview,

```
fun getBottomCutBackground(activity: Activity): MaterialShapeDrawable {
    val bottomCut = ShapeAppearanceModel()
        .toBuilder()
        .setTopRightCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED, 16F)
        .setTopLeftCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED, 16F)
        .setBottomLeftCorner(CutoutCornersTreatment(16F))
        .setBottomRightCorner(CutoutCornersTreatment(16F))
        .build()

    return MaterialShapeDrawable(bottomCut).apply {
        setTint(ContextCompat.getColor(activity, R.color.white))
        paintStyle = Paint.Style.FILL
    }
}
```

It works well on API 29 and above

I'm using `androidx.cardview.widget.CardView` and also tried with     `com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView`

If I use `LinearLayout` instead of `CardView` my view looks good.

Interestingly, `CardView` goes invisible but I can interact with it (can tap to button and go to another activity)

```
 <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:focusable="true">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: Have you tried adding elavation to it? `app:cardElevation="@dimen/elevation"` where `@dimen/elavtion` is a resource declared in your `dimens.xml` with a value of `8dp` or something? Would help to show the xml so we can see how it looks. Also are elements on it not visible or just the `CardView` itself?

Comment: @DavidKroukamp yes I tried, no luck, CardView itself and contents in it are not visible

Comment: Maybe post some more code like the xml and how you use the code shown so others can replicate and potentially find a solution.  Also if you dont call `getBottomCutBackground` does it show?

Comment: Have you tried to use a MaterialCard instead of androidx Card?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti, just tried, same error

Comment: @EmreAkcan not sure about the `setTint` method. Maybe `setFillColor` is better.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti removed setTint completely, still same issue (ofc card is black below 29 because I removed it) it is not visible <29